# I want to consume two kafka different topic in one .net5 project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, apache-kafka, dependency-injection, consumer

I have a .net5 project and write code for consuming different kafka topics.

Everything is ok when i only consume one topic - one group, but if i put another topic for consuming it, only first topic-group consumed but another is not.

My code is like that;

Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(o =>
            { 
                o.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ActivateMovieConsumerHandler>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, DeactivateMovieConsumerHandler>();
            services.AddElasticsearch(Configuration);
            services.AddScoped<IElasticService, ElasticService>();
        }
```

First consumerhandler code for activated

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Logic.Business.Service.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Logic.Business.Service.Kafka.Handlers
{
    public class ActivateMovieConsumerHandler : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IElasticService _elasticService;
        
        public ActivateMovieConsumerHandler(IConfiguration configuration, IElasticService elasticService)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _elasticService = elasticService;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var conf = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = _configuration["MovieActivatedGroupName"],
                BootstrapServers = _configuration["KafkaBootstrapServers"],
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };
            
            using (var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, 
                string>(conf).Build())
            {
                builder.Subscribe(_configuration["MovieActivatedTopicName"]);
                var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                while (true)
                {
                    var consumer = builder.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
                    try
                    {
                        _elasticService.InsertMovie(consumer.Message.Value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        builder.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

And second consumer handler for deactivated

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Logic.Business.Service.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Logic.Business.Service.Kafka.Handlers
{
    public class DeactivateMovieConsumerHandler : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IElasticService _elasticService;
        
        public DeactivateMovieConsumerHandler(IConfiguration configuration, IElasticService elasticService)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _elasticService = elasticService;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var conf = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = _configuration["MovieDeactivatedGroupName"],
                BootstrapServers = _configuration["KafkaBootstrapServers"],
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };
            
            using (var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, 
                string>(conf).Build())
            {
                builder.Subscribe(_configuration["MovieDeactivatedTopicName"]);
                var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                while (true)
                {
                    var consumer = builder.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
                    try
                    {
                        _elasticService.DeleteMovie(consumer.Message.Value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        builder.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

As seen above in startup.cs; I put two dependencies for activated and deactivated but the code runs for only first handler, other is not listening on program

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem with adding new thread for new consumer

My final code is below

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Logic.Business.Service.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Logic.Business.Service.Kafka.Handlers
{
    public class MovieConsumerHandler : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IElasticService _elasticService;
        
        public MovieConsumerHandler(IConfiguration configuration, IElasticService elasticService)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _elasticService = elasticService;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Thread activatedThread = new Thread(StartActivatedConsumer)
            {
                Name = "ActivatedThread"
            };
            
            Thread deactivatedThread = new Thread(StartDeactivatedConsumer)
            {
                Name = "DeactivatedThread"
            };
            
            activatedThread.Start();  
            deactivatedThread.Start();
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void StartActivatedConsumer()
        {
            var conf = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = _configuration["MovieActivatedGroupName"],
                BootstrapServers = _configuration["KafkaBootstrapServers"],
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };
            
            using (var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, 
                string>(conf).Build())
            {
                builder.Subscribe(_configuration["MovieActivatedTopicName"]);
                var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                while (true)
                {
                    var consumer = builder.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
                    try
                    {
                        _elasticService.InsertMovie(consumer.Message.Value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        builder.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void StartDeactivatedConsumer()
        {
            var conf = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = _configuration["MovieDeactivatedGroupName"],
                BootstrapServers = _configuration["KafkaBootstrapServers"],
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };
            
            using (var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, 
                string>(conf).Build())
            {
                builder.Subscribe(_configuration["MovieDeactivatedTopicName"]);
                var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                while (true)
                {
                    var consumer = builder.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
                    try
                    {
                        _elasticService.DeleteMovie(consumer.Message.Value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        builder.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

In .net if we don't mark another thread then one thread has started, so far I make new thread and then consume another topic

Comment: You dont necessarily need a thread. One consumer can subscribe to multiple topics